# How to find web element in polymer page for selenium?

Tags: selenium

i'm trying to find a web element in a web page coded with Polymer,
the source is:

```
<iron-ally-announcer>==0
<div class="style-scope iron-ally-announcer" aria-live="polite">Invalid    credentials</div>
</iron-ally-announcer>
```

I can find with xpath but i want to find by classname or id
if i try =

```
driver.findElement(By.className("style-scope iron-ally-announcer"));
```

it cannot find.
The element is an alert message.

Answer (score 0):

`By.className` receives one class as parameter, `style-scope` and `iron-ally-announcer` are actually two classes in that WebElement. It should be

```
driver.findElement(By.className("style-scope"));
// or
driver.findElement(By.className("iron-ally-announcer"));
```

If you want to use both of them you can do it with `cssSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".style-scope.iron-ally-announcer"));
```

Comment: @TemplogLog Is it inside `<frame>` or `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: it's inside but i try this  driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/iron-a11y-announcer")).click(); because in the alert message there is a button which i can click and i got this error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (0, 0). Other element would receive the click: <div id="background" class="layout vertical style-scope load-window">...</div>

Comment: @TemplogLog You need to switch to the frame to interact with the elements inside it `driver.switchTo().frame("frame Id / frame name")`